# How could I add to a table from from a different model HTML page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails. I have a table `TeamMemberships` that has a foreign key to `Students` and a foreign key to `Teams`. I want to be able to have a link in the `show.html.erb` page for a specific team that redirects to a form that lets me add a row to `TeamMemberships` in which the `Team` foreign key is the team whose `show.html.erb` page the link was clicked on and the `Student` foreign key would be determined by the form. Is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a new resources in your `routes.rb` file like so:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :teams do
    resources :team_memberships
  end
end
```

Which will create the CRUD routes:

```
      team_team_memberships GET    /teams/:team_id/team_memberships(.:format)                        team_memberships#index
                            POST   /teams/:team_id/team_memberships(.:format)                        team_memberships#create
   new_team_team_membership GET    /teams/:team_id/team_memberships/new(.:format)                    team_memberships#new
  edit_team_team_membership GET    /teams/:team_id/team_memberships/:id/edit(.:format)               team_memberships#edit
       team_team_membership GET    /teams/:team_id/team_memberships/:id(.:format)                    team_memberships#show
                            PATCH  /teams/:team_id/team_memberships/:id(.:format)                    team_memberships#update
                            PUT    /teams/:team_id/team_memberships/:id(.:format)                    team_memberships#update
                            DELETE /teams/:team_id/team_memberships/:id(.:format)                    team_memberships#destroy
```

What is interesting you here is the `new_team_team_membership GET    /teams/:team_id/team_memberships/new(.:format)` that you can call using the named route `new_team_team_membership`.
You will be able to pass the team ID for which you'd like to create the `TeamMembership` in the route with `new_team_team_membership_path(@team.id)`.\
Regarding the `student_id` you will pass it in the HTTP POST request body.

Here is how to create the link from the team show page to the TeamMembership form:

```
<%= link_to 'Add a student', new_team_team_membership_path(@team.id) %>
```

You will have to create the `TeamMembershipsController` and the `new` action. The action should initialise the `@new_team_membership` variable that will be used by the form and load the student list like so:

```rb
class TeamMembershipsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @new_team_membership = TeamMembership.new(team_id: params[:team_id])
    @students = Student.all
  end
end
```

Then you have to create the `app/views/team_memberships/` folder and add the `new.html.erb` file with the following form:

```
<%= form_for @new_team_membership do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :student_id, options_for_select(@students.collect{ |student| [student.name, student.id]) %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your `TeamMembershipsController` controller, you have to define the `create` action that will receive in parameter the `team_id`, and from the form the selected `student_id`. You will then be able to create the TeamMembership instance.

### Update

Regarding the `create` action of the `TeamMembershipsController` controller, here is how it should be done:

```rb
class TeamMembershipsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # ...
  end

  def create
    # The form should have embedded all the params within a key with the model's name
    # like `:team_membership`.
    student = Student.find(params[:team_membership][:student_id])

    @team_membership = TeamMembership.new(
      team_id: params[:team_id],
      student: student
    )

    if @team_membership.save
      redirect_to :team_path(params[:team_id])
    else
      # Reload again the student as we will show errors.
      # The student dropdown would be empty.
      @students = Student.all

      # Render again the new form
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: how would I go about modifying the `create` action such that it will receive these parameters? When I use it how it is, I get an error saying "NoMethodError in TeamMemberships#create: undefined method 'collect' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Use [collection_select](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) `f.collection_select :student_id, Student.all, :id, :name` instead of the lower level `select` helper. You don't get bonus points for doing it the hard way.

Comment: @astronautical_22 I've added an example of the `create` action. Please let me know if it helps.